# How to insert multiple lines in cards in Trello

Tags: trello

I would like to add text in multiple lines in a card in Trello.
I tried pressing ENTER and pressing ENTER+SHIFT but not working.

Comment: Multiple Lines cannot be used in the Card Name. [Supporting Link](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20492/how-do-i-insert-a-carriage-return-on-a-card-in-trello)